# what to do when custom page setup not working on printer

Tags: c#, printing, reporting, devexpress

i am doing some changes in application developed in c#.net 3.5 , application using devxpress for reporting , customer has dot matrix printer epson lx 300 + with running paper size (32cm height and 22 cm width).
problem is some reports are very large and require every mm of page to print reports so i setup page size a4extra (32cm height and 22 cm width ) but problem is printer not  recognizing page setup it always give a4 print size which leaves reports half printed and after some pages printed new soft page start on middle of physical page so soft pages not printed separately on physical pages so result is ugly report print

i also added same(a4extra) paper size to printer but it not recognizing i used notepad/word but result is same

so 
1 how to allow printer to recognize custom paper size is i am missing something ?
2 if printer is dumb and i am forced to work with a4 how can i keep each soft page on each physical page without mixing them ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the printer does not support this paper size and thus your attempt to print such large documents did not succeed.
So, I suggest that you use the following code to fit your report to an existing paper size:

```
report.PrintingSystem.Document.AutoFitToDocumentWidth = 1;
```